# Why are $E[X]_, \;E[Y]= 0$ if $X_,\; Y$ are measured from their means?

Tags: expectation

I was studying some examples of *linear correlations* where I got the reasoning:

> Since $X_,\;Y$ are measured from their means, $$E[X]= 0=E[Y]$$ ....

Can anyone tell me why it is so?

Comment: What does "measured from their means" mean?

Comment: Now, if I had known, would I have raised this question? I'm really in the blues.

Comment: Can you give more information about the context? Is it about linear (regression) models and if so, is $X$ random?

Comment: @Nigel Overmars: There is really no more info actually:( I can only post that example-question, which, IMO, is unrelated to the line used in the reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what *"measured from the means"* means, consider the following example. Let $X$ be the random variable that measures the temperature in a place with mean temperature $E[X]=20^o$C. Let the temperature be $X=21$ at some given day. You can either write $X=21^o$ or $X=21-20=1$. In the second case you *"measure $X$ from its mean"*. Similarly $X=19^o$ can be written as $X=-2$ etc. So, you use a new variable $$X'=X-μ$$ where $μ=Ε[Χ]$. Obviously $$E[X']=E[X-μ]=E[X]-E[X]=0$$ Τo avoid unnecessary notation, the author does not denote this new variable with $X'$ and just says that $X$ is *"measured from its mean"*. Similarly for $Y$. You may also encounter the term *"centered random variables"*. It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think means than the axis is centerded on their means. Think about if we know the mean of a r.v. we can center the r.v. by substracting the mean.